# python bluetooth.discover_devices() doesn't detect iphone - other options?

Tags: python, bluetooth, detection

I'm trying to detect my phone using bluetooth.

My phone is right next to my laptop, but still no device is detected.

Is there some other way I can detect if an iphone or android is in close proximity? Ideally I'd like to be able to tell if the phone is within **1.4 m** from the laptop.

Thanks!

```
from bluetooth import *
nearby_devices = discover_devices(lookup_names = True)
print(f'found {len(nearby_devices)} devices') 
for name, addr in nearby_devices:
    print(f'{addr} - {name}')
# Output
found 0 devices
```

Comment: Is your phone in discoverable mode or paired with the scanning device?

Comment: @ Klaus D. my phone is in discoverable model.

Comment: @Jimmy before doing it via Python, check from your laptop's built-in scanner app if you can detect it or not.